# How can I add an async validator to an input field?

Tags: angularjs

In the documentation it shows this:

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  var value = modelValue || viewValue;

  // Lookup user by username
  return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
     then(function resolved() {
       //username exists, this means validation fails
       return $q.reject('exists');
     }, function rejected() {
       //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
       return true;
     });
};
```

But how do I connect this with an input field? It doesn't give an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd apply your validator inside of a directive `link` function. The directive must require `ngModel`, and then you'd apply that directive as an attribute to the input tag. In your case, that might look a bit like this:

```
angular.directive('isUniqueName', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;

        // Lookup user by username
        return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
          then(function resolved() {
            //username exists, this means validation fails
            return $q.reject('exists');
          }, function rejected() {
            //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
            return true;
          })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

And then in your HTML code:

```
<input type='text' name='username' ng-model='username' is-unique-name />
```